# Chrome extension message passing between content and background not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension, here are the main files:

**`background.js`**

```
getPageDimension = function (){
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { message: "DIMENSION" }, function(response){
            if (response != null) {
                console.log(response.x);
                console.log(response.y);
                console.log(response.w);
                console.log(response.h);
            }else{
                console.log('Response is null');
            }
        });
    }); 
};
```

**`content.js`**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {        
    if (msg.message && (msg.message == "DIMENSION")) {                          
        var dimension = getPageDiemension(document.documentElement);        
        console.log(dimension.x);
        console.log(dimension.y);
        console.log(dimension.w);
        console.log(dimension.h);
        sendResponse({x: dimension.x, y: dimension.y,w: dimension.w,h: dimension.h});       
    }
});

getPageDiemension = function(currentDom){
    var dimension = new Object();
    dimension.x = 0;
    dimension.y = 0;
    dimension.w = currentDom.scrollWidth;
    dimension.h = currentDom.scrollHeight;
    return dimension;
}
```

So my aim is to get the full height and width of page loaded in current active tab. When I **debug** my content script, I get the proper response in my **background.js**, but if run the script without debugging, I get an `undefined` response in my `background.js`.

Here is the declaration of my `cotent.js` in my `manifest.json` file:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "all_frames": true,
    "matches": [
        "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
    ],
        "js": ["content.js"]
}],
```

Kindly help me, where am I going wrong?. Let me know if you need any further data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Issues

There are two little problems in your code, which I found after a wile, since that it looks perfectly working (when it isn't at all).

1. You're using the deprecated `chrome.tabs.getSelected(...)` method, which you should avoid. Use `chrome.tabs.query({active: true, highlighted: true}, ...)` instead.
2. In your `chrome.runtime.onMessage` listener, in the content script, you are doing some calculations before sending the response: this makes the message channel close before you can send a response, and will result in a `null` response.

   Quoting from [the official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage):

   > This function (`sendResponse`) becomes invalid when the event listener returns, unless you return `true` from the event listener to indicate you wish to send a response asynchronously (this will keep the message channel open to the other end until `sendResponse` is called).

### Solution

Now that you know what the problems are, you can easily replace the old `tabs.getSelected()` with `tabs.query()`, and add a `return true;` statement in the handler of the `runtime.onMessage` event in your content script. The solution is the following, I also lightened the code a bit.

Your `background.js`:

```
getPageDimension = function (){
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, highlighted: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { message: "DIMENSION" }, function(response){
            if (response !== null) console.log('Response:', response);
            else console.log('Response is null');
        });
    }); 
};
```

Your `content.js`:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {        
    if (msg.message && (msg.message == "DIMENSION")) {                          
        var dimension = getPageDiemension(document.documentElement); 
        console.log('Dimension:', dimension);
        sendResponse(dimension);       
    }
    return true;
});

getPageDiemension = function(currentDom){
    return { x: 0, y: 0,
        w: currentDom.scrollWidth,
        h: currentDom.scrollHeight
    }
}
```

### Working example

You can find a working example I made for testing **[HERE](http://www.mediafire.com/download/13saoah7bw9ahti/extension-27823740.zip)**.

### Documentation links

Just for clarity, I'm leaving you some documentation links regarding the APIs involved in this extension that you may find helpful:

- [`chrome.tabs` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs)

  - [`chrome.tabs.query` method](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query)
- [Chrome extension message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)

  - [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage` method](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage)
  - [`chrome.runtime.onMessage` event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the wonderful example and detailed insight :)