# Chrome extension message passing between content and background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been testing this for a few good hours, I've also taken a, known to work at the time, example. See here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27829709/2430488

Its just not working for me or I'm not sure how to test. I'm opening the developer tools, and also the extension developer tools, but nothing is being logged in either window.

The code I'm using:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Some test",
    "description": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27823740",
    "version": "0",

    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ] 
    },

    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"],

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["cont.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

**cont.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {        
    if (msg.message && (msg.message == "DIMENSION")) {                          
        var dimension = getPageDiemension(document.documentElement);        
        console.log('Dimension:', dimension);
        sendResponse(dimension);       
    }
        return true;
});

getPageDiemension = function(currentDom){
    return {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        w: currentDom.scrollWidth,
        h: currentDom.scrollHeight
    }
}
```

**background.js**

```
getPageDimension = function (){
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, highlighted: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { message: "DIMENSION" }, function(response){
            if (response !== null) console.log('Response:', response);
            else console.log('Response is null');
        });
    }); 
    };
```

Please help, I really am not sure what I'm doing wrong, I've been looking at the documentation for the last few hours but I can't understand why is not working.

Thank you.

Comment: Where's your call to `getPageDimension` in background.js?

Comment: in cont.js `var dimension = getPageDiemension(document.documentElement); `
basically I need to pass a message from the background script to the content script. If that makes sense ...

Answer (score 1):

As rsanchez mentions, your background defines a function `getPageDimension`.

It is then never called, so your extension does exactly nothing. There doesn't seem to be any error, you just never *do* anything.

You need to bind a call to `getPageDimension` to some event, e.g. clicking a [Browser Action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction).